# getting this npm react component to work with meteor

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Using [react-typeahead-component](https://github.com/ezequiel/react-typeahead-component)
I used [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to change it from npm into a meteor local package. Nothing is showing on the screen when i run meteor.

OptionTemplate.jsx

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

    return (
        <div>
           <p>HELLO</p>
        </div>
    );
},
    handleChange: function(event) {
        console.log('HELLO');
}

});
```

main.jsx

```
var OptionTemplate = require('./OptionTemplate.jsx');

SearchBox = React.createClass({render() {
  return (
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
      <OptionTemplate />
    </div>
  )}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using components properly. You might want to re-read the react documentation.

In your main.jsx, you are importing the component 'OptionTemplate' but you are trying to render the component 'Typeahead' and passing in 'OptionTemplate' as a prop. The 'Typeahead' component now lives in 'OptionTemplate'. Your main.jsx should like like:

```
var OptionTemplate = require('./OptionTemplate.jsx');

SearchBox = React.createClass({render() {
  return (
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
      <OptionTemplate />
    </div>
  )}
});
```

Comment: hold on a sec.. but.. Thats what the docs say? https://github.com/ezequiel/react-typeahead-component    look at Available Props Example.

Comment: Strange, I've never seen anyone do that before. Sorry about that. There are some examples in the repo, check out https://github.com/ezequiel/react-typeahead-component/tree/master/example/youtube/js. Typeahead is in app.jsx and OptionTemplate is is /components